Isekai manga where the main character has an inventory skill and teaches how to improve metalworking
This manga starts of with the MC waking up in a field.
Where he is then forced into a tree by a pack of wolves.
He then checks his skills and finds out he has an large inventory.
He then makes it to a town and helps out with his inventory skill by moving a bunch of stuff.
One-day he finds a child and asks people to find out where she is from. I believe that the Mc finds the child being kidnapped and saves her. The kid was strong as she could bend a pipe that was made for either metal or mithril.
The Mc also helps the denizens with advancing their technology notably their smithing where he teaches them how to temper their iron and how to make a new fuel source rather than using wood.
iirc the Mc was also able to kill a super defensive monster which was like a giant turtle with magic and something. I think I recall that it was a very impressive feat. The Mc used a short wand and had a large inventory.
There is a manga called: Isekai de Te ni Ireta Seisan Skill wa Saikyou datta You desu. But it is not this one. It has a similar beginning but is different.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Thank you, it has been a few years since I've read it. I do not remember exactly where I read it as the website I used may have been removed. I apologize for not being any help.

its this one:
Isekai Ten'ishita Node Cheat wo Ikashite Mahou Kenshi Yaru Koto ni Suru
found from this post:
https://old.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/12b2elr/after_looking_through_1000_mangas_and_reading/
